# Draw quad in Delphi and OpenGL - background is painted in black

Tags: delphi, opengl, background

I need help with drawing a simple quad (this is only a test for drawing textures later) in Delphi and OpenGL. The quad is drawn correctly, but the rest of the form is painted in black. I'll have a background image on the form so I want that rest of the form's canvas stay unchanged.

I'm trying to use scissor, but no luck. I'm open for any other suggestions.  Maybe using OpenGL viewport or.....

Here is mu code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.OpenGL;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    RC: HGLRC;
    DC: HDC;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pfd: TPixelFormatDescriptor;
  PixelFormat: Integer;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Handle);

  ZeroMemory(@pfd, SizeOf(pfd));
  pfd.nSize := SizeOf(pfd);
  pfd.nVersion := 1;
  pfd.dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  pfd.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits := 24;
  pfd.cDepthBits := 16;
  pfd.iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

  PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(DC, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(DC, PixelFormat, @pfd);

  RC := wglCreateContext(DC);
  wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
  wglDeleteContext(RC);
  ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
  glScissor(ClientWidth div 4, ClientHeight div 4, ClientWidth div 2, ClientHeight div 2);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-ClientWidth / 2, ClientWidth / 2, -ClientHeight / 2, ClientHeight / 2, -1, 1);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-50, -50);
    glVertex2f(-50, 50);
    glVertex2f(50, 50);
    glVertex2f(50, -50);
  glEnd();

  glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

  SwapBuffers(DC);
end;

end.
```

I think that this should work, but it doesn't. I've tried with ALPHA BLEND functions but I've must be doing something wrong. I don't want to use any background color and want to draw background image only once. Area of the quad will change.

Here are additional explanation what am I trying.

Screen sesolution is 1920x1080. Delphi form is covered whole screen. Form has a background. In the center of the form I need OpenGL window where I'll have animation with 60 FPS. The rest of the window is pretty much static. I'm trying not to draw the entire whole screen with every form.

[image]

Even if I set "glViewport (200, 150, 1520, 780);" area outside of OpenGL window is painted black.

Maybe this is wrong:

```
  RC := wglCreateContext(DC);
  wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC);
```

Maybe I could do it but I think that I'll have some other idipendent animation at the top of the window which will have different FPS (15-20 FPS). I'm not sure how that will work if I draw whole window every time.

Answer (score 0):

To define the back ground color, you can use `glClearColor(r, g, b, a)`, where the parameters are of type single, and values are 0 .. 1.0.

The parameters `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` stand for `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha`.

By default, the background is black, as if `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0) would have been issued.

To get a fairly light background, try

```
glClearColor(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
```

as the first line in your `FormPaint` procedure.

The result looks like this:

[image]

You should absolutely get hold of some documentation, e.g. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/

Comment: Thanks Tom. I know how I can clear color from black to some other color. But I don't want to use any color. There is a background image that has been drawn on the form earlier in  the program. I want that background image to stay visible whole the time, and only the part of the form where the quad is drawn should be changed/refreshed/rendered.

Comment: Well, it sounded as the black bg was the main issue as you even mention it in the title of your question: "... OpenGl - background is painted in black". But if your image covers the whole window, then you don't need to care about the background being initialized to black before you paint the image, or ... maybe I don't get the real issue. Are you looking for layered rendering where you could update just one layer and visible parts of deeper layers would be undisturbed (automatically redrawn by OpenGL)? I don't know if that is possible in OpenGL. If not, then you need to do it yourself.

Comment: I've a form that is 1000x600 px. And there is a background image drawn on that form that covers a whole form. There are different colors and shapes on that form. Now I want to draw a red quad 180x90 pox on that form where the top left corner of the quad is at 35, 50. Background image around that quad should stay intact. Now it is painted in black or any other color that I set as clean color.

Comment: @brane: OpenGL takes full control of its region. You cannot combine GDI and OpenGL drawing. Within the OpenGL window (or "rectangle"), you can only draw using OpenGL, and you can only draw one frame at a time (in response to `WM_PAINT`). You can, however, of course make the OpenGL window only cover a part of your form. And you can also use OpenGL to draw any background you want in the OpenGL window before you draw your OpenGL quad. Alternatively, you can draw your OpenGL picture to an off-screen buffer and then use any method you like to (possibly alpha) draw this on your form.

Comment: Thank you Andreas. That is exactly what I want to accomplish, but I don't know how. I've edited a question with additional explanation what I need.